# Processing a stream of JSON objects (using Java, preferably)

Tags: java, json

I am attempting to process a continuous stream of JSON objects (meetup provides a [public stream](https://www.meetup.com/meetup_api/docs/stream/2/rsvps) of its RSVPs). I have several days of this data saved to various files (each file containing many JSON objects). I would like to parse these files ("offline" processing), as well as process data as it arrives ("real-time" processing).

So far, I have been able to parse a single JSON object in a single file using the `javax.json.stream` package, illustrated [here](http://www.journaldev.com/2315/java-json-example).

However, this package understands a stream as "element-by-element," where a JSON object is composed of many such elements. If I try to use it with multiple JSON objects in a single text file, the `hasNext()` function throws `Expected EOF, but got CURLYOPEN` at the end of the first object.
I understand that valid JSON format is *one object per file*. Can I still somehow use this package to process a large file with many JSON objects, and an incoming stream? If so, how?

==============

Update 1: Thanks lexicore. So far with Jackson I've been able to parse multiple JSON objects in a single text file. I have yet to try it for real-time JSON stream processing.

Update 2: I'm also able to use Jackson for real-time stream processing. I write the stream to a file, and read this file using Jackson. If I hit the end of the file, I catch the exception and back-off for a few seconds.

Comment: This should work with Jackson: https://blog.avisi.nl/2012/11/29/jackson-and-parsing-streams-a-short-story-about-a-big-pile-o-json/